# Codeigniter: How to group host url and save it to database in case of multiple item?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am asking for following details from user in form:

- Product name:
- product Price:
- Product URL:

The user can add multiple items in cart. During checkout, I want to filter URL like if user enter below multiple URL in the form and these multiple url's will be inserted in products table.

- aliexpress.com/product/phone_cover
- aliexpress.com/product/phone_battery
- nike.com/cat/shoes

In this case I want to get host (Domain) of URL like:

- aliexpress.com
- nike.com

and add once in the database store table.
For example, user added 2 URLs from aliexpress and one for nike so I want to store one time aliexpress and one time nike in store_url column of store table in database.
I am getting host URL by the code below:

```
foreach ($data as $show) 
{
    $var= parse_url($show->produst_url);                                                                                                
    echo $var['host'];
}
```

below are database tables

```
--------        -------
products         store
--------        -------
id              id
product name    products_id
product url     store url
product price
```

Any help is appreciated. I have tried my best to explain you my problem but if you still need some more detail I will be happy to explain you more. Thanks

Comment: Your question lacks a clear problem statement. For one I don't see any db related code.

Comment: @Alex oh sorry. Now i have added database columns and i am just fetching product url from database.Question is lengthy so that is why i have not model code. i am showing view file code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are many ways to do this and this is just one of them...

Your primary question is - how do you save unique entries?

This is just some sample code, based upon what you provided with debug so I could see how it was working as I developed it.  There is NO Database "stuff" as you haven't provided any information regarding it, so it's just a starter to get you going.

```
// Create some dummy test data as per the provided code.
$data[] = (object)array('produst_url' => 'http://aliexpress.com/product/phone_cover');
$data[] = (object)array('produst_url' => 'http://aliexpress.com/product/phone_battery');
$data[] = (object)array('produst_url' => 'http://nike.com/cat/shoes');

var_dump($data); // Check the test array

$host_array = array(); // Init the array to store the host values

foreach ($data as $show) {
    $var = parse_url($show->produst_url);
    var_dump($var); // Check the $var array

    $host = $var['host'];

    // Save the host name in the host_array ONLY if it hasn't already been saved.
    if ( ! in_array($host, $host_array)) {
        $host_array[] = $host;
    }
    echo $host; // show the host name
}

// Check the final $host_array

var_dump($host_array); // What does the final answer look like?
```

The final var_dump ,var_dump($host_array), reveals...

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'aliexpress.com' (length=14)
  1 => string 'nike.com' (length=8)
```

Not sure if **produst** should be **product** but I kept it as you had it. At least it is consistent.

So now you have an array of **unique host names**. Next you have to save them into the database IF they are not already there, to prevent duplicates.

As you have not provided any insight into your database/table setup,that part should be another question if you are unsure on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you @TimBrownlaw. i have edited my question and added database table too. You have answered it well. Can you plzz guide me little more like if i dont know that how many multiple url's user will add then how i can get them and store them in database?